# Convert Phone Number to International with Country Code iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that reads in the user's contact list, but I need to convert each number to the International Equivalent with the Country Code. For example, if a number is 07777777777, then the result would be +447777777777, or if a number was from Turkey and it was 0090, it would replace it with +90.

```
- (NSString *)ConvertNumberToInternational:(NSString *)number {
if(number != nil) {
    if(number.length > 0) {
        NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
        NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
        NSDictionary *dict = [self dictCountryCodes];
        number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        if([[number substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![[number substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"00"]) {
            number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+44%@", [number stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:[number rangeOfString:@"0"] withString:@""]];
        }
        if([[number substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"00"]) {
            number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@%@", [dict objectForKey:countryCode], [number substringFromIndex:2]];
        }
        number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "  withString:@""];
    }
}
return number;
}

-(NSDictionary *)dictCountryCodes{
NSDictionary *dictCodes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"93", @"AF",@"20",@"EG", @"355", @"AL", @"213", @"DZ", @"1", @"AS",
                           @"376", @"AD", @"244", @"AO", @"1", @"AI", @"1", @"AG",
                           @"54", @"AR", @"374", @"AM", @"297", @"AW", @"61", @"AU",
                           @"43", @"AT", @"994", @"AZ", @"1", @"BS", @"973", @"BH",
                           @"880", @"BD", @"1", @"BB", @"375", @"BY", @"32", @"BE",
                           @"501", @"BZ", @"229", @"BJ", @"1", @"BM", @"975", @"BT",
                           @"387", @"BA", @"267", @"BW", @"55", @"BR", @"246", @"IO",
                           @"359", @"BG", @"226", @"BF", @"257", @"BI", @"855", @"KH",
                           @"237", @"CM", @"1", @"CA", @"238", @"CV", @"345", @"KY",
                           @"236", @"CF", @"235", @"TD", @"56", @"CL", @"86", @"CN",
                           @"61", @"CX", @"57", @"CO", @"269", @"KM", @"242", @"CG",
                           @"682", @"CK", @"506", @"CR", @"385", @"HR", @"53", @"CU",
                           @"537", @"CY", @"420", @"CZ", @"45", @"DK", @"253", @"DJ",
                           @"1", @"DM", @"1", @"DO", @"593", @"EC", @"20", @"EG",
                           @"503", @"SV", @"240", @"GQ", @"291", @"ER", @"372", @"EE",
                           @"251", @"ET", @"298", @"FO", @"679", @"FJ", @"358", @"FI",
                           @"33", @"FR", @"594", @"GF", @"689", @"PF", @"241", @"GA",
                           @"220", @"GM", @"995", @"GE", @"49", @"DE", @"233", @"GH",
                           @"350", @"GI", @"30", @"GR", @"299", @"GL", @"1", @"GD",
                           @"590", @"GP", @"1", @"GU", @"502", @"GT", @"224", @"GN",
                           @"245", @"GW", @"595", @"GY", @"509", @"HT", @"504", @"HN",
                           @"36", @"HU", @"354", @"IS", @"91", @"IN", @"62", @"ID",
                           @"964", @"IQ", @"353", @"IE", @"972", @"IL", @"39", @"IT",
                           @"1", @"JM", @"81", @"JP", @"962", @"JO", @"77", @"KZ",
                           @"254", @"KE", @"686", @"KI", @"965", @"KW", @"996", @"KG",
                           @"371", @"LV", @"961", @"LB", @"266", @"LS", @"231", @"LR",
                           @"423", @"LI", @"370", @"LT", @"352", @"LU", @"261", @"MG",
                           @"265", @"MW", @"60", @"MY", @"960", @"MV", @"223", @"ML",
                           @"356", @"MT", @"692", @"MH", @"596", @"MQ", @"222", @"MR",
                           @"230", @"MU", @"262", @"YT", @"52", @"MX", @"377", @"MC",
                           @"976", @"MN", @"382", @"ME", @"1", @"MS", @"212", @"MA",
                           @"95", @"MM", @"264", @"NA", @"674", @"NR", @"977", @"NP",
                           @"31", @"NL", @"599", @"AN", @"687", @"NC", @"64", @"NZ",
                           @"505", @"NI", @"227", @"NE", @"234", @"NG", @"683", @"NU",
                           @"672", @"NF", @"1", @"MP", @"47", @"NO", @"968", @"OM",
                           @"92", @"PK", @"680", @"PW", @"507", @"PA", @"675", @"PG",
                           @"595", @"PY", @"51", @"PE", @"63", @"PH", @"48", @"PL",
                           @"351", @"PT", @"1", @"PR", @"974", @"QA", @"40", @"RO",
                           @"250", @"RW", @"685", @"WS", @"378", @"SM", @"966", @"SA",
                           @"221", @"SN", @"381", @"RS", @"248", @"SC", @"232", @"SL",
                           @"65", @"SG", @"421", @"SK", @"386", @"SI", @"677", @"SB",
                           @"27", @"ZA", @"500", @"GS", @"34", @"ES", @"94", @"LK",
                           @"249", @"SD", @"597", @"SR", @"268", @"SZ", @"46", @"SE",
                           @"41", @"CH", @"992", @"TJ", @"66", @"TH", @"228", @"TG",
                           @"690", @"TK", @"676", @"TO", @"1", @"TT", @"216", @"TN",
                           @"90", @"TR", @"993", @"TM", @"1", @"TC", @"688", @"TV",
                           @"256", @"UG", @"380", @"UA", @"971", @"AE", @"44", @"GB",
                           @"1", @"US", @"598", @"UY", @"998", @"UZ", @"678", @"VU",
                           @"681", @"WF", @"967", @"YE", @"260", @"ZM", @"263", @"ZW",
                           @"591", @"BO", @"673", @"BN", @"61", @"CC", @"243", @"CD",
                           @"225", @"CI", @"500", @"FK", @"44", @"GG", @"379", @"VA",
                           @"852", @"HK", @"98", @"IR", @"44", @"IM", @"44", @"JE",
                           @"850", @"KP", @"82", @"KR", @"856", @"LA", @"218", @"LY",
                           @"853", @"MO", @"389", @"MK", @"691", @"FM", @"373", @"MD",
                           @"258", @"MZ", @"970", @"PS", @"872", @"PN", @"262", @"RE",
                           @"7", @"RU", @"590", @"BL", @"290", @"SH", @"1", @"KN",
                           @"1", @"LC", @"590", @"MF", @"508", @"PM", @"1", @"VC",
                           @"239", @"ST", @"252", @"SO", @"47", @"SJ", @"963", @"SY",
                           @"886", @"TW", @"255", @"TZ", @"670", @"TL", @"58", @"VE",
                           @"84", @"VN", @"1", @"VG", @"1", @"VI", nil];

return dictCodes;
}
```

The above code does not work, as I am just using the user's current locale. I need to know the locale of the phone number. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: so you assume just 0 is the iphone region always and 00 is the international number 'prefix'

Comment: I've edited my post to show what I have so far, but with an nslocale problem

Comment: don't get it why need the code at all

Comment: Because I need the country code, to replace the 0 with +

Comment: but you have the + anyways... please try my answer with a few numbers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I enter 07777777777 then it converts it to +17777777777, but it should be +447777777777

Comment: It looks like that was just a problem on the simulator. I tried running this on my phone and it looks good to me. Thanks, I have marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so you assume just 0 is the iphone region always and 00 is the international number 'prefix' –

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface T : NSObject
@end

@implementation T

- (NSString *)convertNumberToInternational:(NSString *)number {
    if(number != nil) {
        if(number.length > 0) {
            NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
            NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
            NSDictionary *dict = [self dictCountryCodes];
            NSString *localNumberCode = dict[countryCode];

            number = [number stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

            if([[number substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![[number substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"00"]) {
                number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@%@", localNumberCode, [number substringFromIndex:1]];
            }
            else if([[number substringToIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"00"]) {
                number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@", [number substringFromIndex:2]];
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
}

-(NSDictionary *)dictCountryCodes{
NSDictionary *dictCodes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"93", @"AF",@"20",@"EG", @"355", @"AL", @"213", @"DZ", @"1", @"AS",
                           @"376", @"AD", @"244", @"AO", @"1", @"AI", @"1", @"AG",
                           @"54", @"AR", @"374", @"AM", @"297", @"AW", @"61", @"AU",
                           @"43", @"AT", @"994", @"AZ", @"1", @"BS", @"973", @"BH",
                           @"880", @"BD", @"1", @"BB", @"375", @"BY", @"32", @"BE",
                           @"501", @"BZ", @"229", @"BJ", @"1", @"BM", @"975", @"BT",
                           @"387", @"BA", @"267", @"BW", @"55", @"BR", @"246", @"IO",
                           @"359", @"BG", @"226", @"BF", @"257", @"BI", @"855", @"KH",
                           @"237", @"CM", @"1", @"CA", @"238", @"CV", @"345", @"KY",
                           @"236", @"CF", @"235", @"TD", @"56", @"CL", @"86", @"CN",
                           @"61", @"CX", @"57", @"CO", @"269", @"KM", @"242", @"CG",
                           @"682", @"CK", @"506", @"CR", @"385", @"HR", @"53", @"CU",
                           @"537", @"CY", @"420", @"CZ", @"45", @"DK", @"253", @"DJ",
                           @"1", @"DM", @"1", @"DO", @"593", @"EC", @"20", @"EG",
                           @"503", @"SV", @"240", @"GQ", @"291", @"ER", @"372", @"EE",
                           @"251", @"ET", @"298", @"FO", @"679", @"FJ", @"358", @"FI",
                           @"33", @"FR", @"594", @"GF", @"689", @"PF", @"241", @"GA",
                           @"220", @"GM", @"995", @"GE", @"49", @"DE", @"233", @"GH",
                           @"350", @"GI", @"30", @"GR", @"299", @"GL", @"1", @"GD",
                           @"590", @"GP", @"1", @"GU", @"502", @"GT", @"224", @"GN",
                           @"245", @"GW", @"595", @"GY", @"509", @"HT", @"504", @"HN",
                           @"36", @"HU", @"354", @"IS", @"91", @"IN", @"62", @"ID",
                           @"964", @"IQ", @"353", @"IE", @"972", @"IL", @"39", @"IT",
                           @"1", @"JM", @"81", @"JP", @"962", @"JO", @"77", @"KZ",
                           @"254", @"KE", @"686", @"KI", @"965", @"KW", @"996", @"KG",
                           @"371", @"LV", @"961", @"LB", @"266", @"LS", @"231", @"LR",
                           @"423", @"LI", @"370", @"LT", @"352", @"LU", @"261", @"MG",
                           @"265", @"MW", @"60", @"MY", @"960", @"MV", @"223", @"ML",
                           @"356", @"MT", @"692", @"MH", @"596", @"MQ", @"222", @"MR",
                           @"230", @"MU", @"262", @"YT", @"52", @"MX", @"377", @"MC",
                           @"976", @"MN", @"382", @"ME", @"1", @"MS", @"212", @"MA",
                           @"95", @"MM", @"264", @"NA", @"674", @"NR", @"977", @"NP",
                           @"31", @"NL", @"599", @"AN", @"687", @"NC", @"64", @"NZ",
                           @"505", @"NI", @"227", @"NE", @"234", @"NG", @"683", @"NU",
                           @"672", @"NF", @"1", @"MP", @"47", @"NO", @"968", @"OM",
                           @"92", @"PK", @"680", @"PW", @"507", @"PA", @"675", @"PG",
                           @"595", @"PY", @"51", @"PE", @"63", @"PH", @"48", @"PL",
                           @"351", @"PT", @"1", @"PR", @"974", @"QA", @"40", @"RO",
                           @"250", @"RW", @"685", @"WS", @"378", @"SM", @"966", @"SA",
                           @"221", @"SN", @"381", @"RS", @"248", @"SC", @"232", @"SL",
                           @"65", @"SG", @"421", @"SK", @"386", @"SI", @"677", @"SB",
                           @"27", @"ZA", @"500", @"GS", @"34", @"ES", @"94", @"LK",
                           @"249", @"SD", @"597", @"SR", @"268", @"SZ", @"46", @"SE",
                           @"41", @"CH", @"992", @"TJ", @"66", @"TH", @"228", @"TG",
                           @"690", @"TK", @"676", @"TO", @"1", @"TT", @"216", @"TN",
                           @"90", @"TR", @"993", @"TM", @"1", @"TC", @"688", @"TV",
                           @"256", @"UG", @"380", @"UA", @"971", @"AE", @"44", @"GB",
                           @"1", @"US", @"598", @"UY", @"998", @"UZ", @"678", @"VU",
                           @"681", @"WF", @"967", @"YE", @"260", @"ZM", @"263", @"ZW",
                           @"591", @"BO", @"673", @"BN", @"61", @"CC", @"243", @"CD",
                           @"225", @"CI", @"500", @"FK", @"44", @"GG", @"379", @"VA",
                           @"852", @"HK", @"98", @"IR", @"44", @"IM", @"44", @"JE",
                           @"850", @"KP", @"82", @"KR", @"856", @"LA", @"218", @"LY",
                           @"853", @"MO", @"389", @"MK", @"691", @"FM", @"373", @"MD",
                           @"258", @"MZ", @"970", @"PS", @"872", @"PN", @"262", @"RE",
                           @"7", @"RU", @"590", @"BL", @"290", @"SH", @"1", @"KN",
                           @"1", @"LC", @"590", @"MF", @"508", @"PM", @"1", @"VC",
                           @"239", @"ST", @"252", @"SO", @"47", @"SJ", @"963", @"SY",
                           @"886", @"TW", @"255", @"TZ", @"670", @"TL", @"58", @"VE",
                           @"84", @"VN", @"1", @"VG", @"1", @"VI", nil];

return dictCodes;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        T*t = [[T alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"%@", [t convertNumberToInternational:@"05135897"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [t convertNumberToInternational:@"00995135897"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed issue that was also there before where 0 could well be at the end or in the middle

Comment: what you have to do to make it UNIVERSAL, make the 00 prefix modular because in some countries it isn't 00 but e.g. 19 or some such number that denotes an international number

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't adress the question as localNumberCode will always be the user's locale and not the one of the phone number from the contact list.

Comment: You're wrong. No country code in number = current country. That's how it generally is and what the op describes. It fits fine. -- What do a YOU want? Maybe you want to Assume a country based on the contacts address. Two more lines but not what was requested here

Comment: My bad. You're right. My mind was bended by the fact that I am trying to solve this. Which I think is really difficult (impossible?). Trying to figure out the country code by looking at the national number.
I ended up using the google libPhoneNumber library. Doesn't really address entirely my need but good enough.

Comment: If the user has a postal address (with country) it is easy

Comment: Or deduce it from mail

Comment: Yes. Might try that. Good suggestions.

Comment: hi i am not understand the above code please help me sort  out this

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use [`NSFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/index.html) class.

Validate the total length of the telephone number. (Which will be entered and read as `NSString`)

There may be few things you may require to do like, skip the first part i.e. `0`.

Comment: I'm just curious. How can we validate number by length, every country has different phone number length.

Comment: @Kampai: That has to be given as a coredata/plist where it is mentioned.

Comment: Ok, So we need some pre collected information for each country's number length, other wise have to use any open source web service right?

Comment: @Kampai: Yes. Since I am not sure if there are any such webservice or pre-defined list is available. Even it may change in due course of time.

Comment: I've edited my post to show what I have so far, but with an nslocale problem